# Comparing elements in the same List Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want to compare the elements in the same `List (The List "list)` and if they are the same print out a line, I'm fairly new to  programming and I dont yet completely understand the **difference** between **List** and an **array** and when you use them.

Someone kindly suggested the code below and although it compliles nothing is being printed out. Since there are two pairs in my array I would expect something to print out at least once. Any help would be most appreciated thanks!

```
                        List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

                        while (search.find()){ 
                            list.add(Double.parseDouble(search.group(1)));
                        }


                        for(int i= 0 ; i < list.size()-1; i++){
                            //System.out.println(list.get(i));  // Successfully prints out all doubles in the SHADING:BUILDING:DETAILED class
                            for(int k = i+1 ; k < list.size() ; k++){
                                if(list.get(i) == list.get(k)){
                                    System.out.println(i + "and" + k + "are pairs");
                                }
                            }
                        }           
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Why would you want to use a List if you have code that works for an Array and you don't know the difference between the two anyway. I strongly suggest reading up on the docs so you get a better understanding of the two so you can figure out which it is you need

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you have coded the comparation repeats itself. Besides, that is not the correct way you access an element in a list, I'm afraid.

For example, lets say you have the i = 0 (value 2.0 for example) and k = 2 (value 5.2), but later you have i = 2 (5.2) and k = 0 (2.0), which is the same. I suggest you the following, which avoids this repetition.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++) 
   for (int k = i+1; k < list.size(); k++) 
      if(list.get(i) == list.get(k))
         System.out.println(i + " and "+ k +" are pairs");
```

Of course, you have to make sure that the list's size is bigger than 1, otherwise it will throw OutOfBoundsException.
Hope this helps ^^

EDIT #2
Try and use the following if, it contains a null-safe equals:

```
if(Objects.equals(list.get(i), list.get(k)))
```

Comment: Thanks this compiles well but I'm not getting anything printed out

Comment: Perhaps there are no numbers that have the same values ^^. Try and add some manually to see if it works properly for you.

Comment: There are definitely numbers that have the same value I'm not sure whats going on I'm trying different formats

Comment: When I have if(list.get(i) != list.get(k)) it prints out so I'm pretty sure there are no issues with the formatting; but the numbers i'm trying to compare are very precise they are for example 2.1612378517 should I be using a double or compare them or something else?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should fix:

```
if(list[i]=  list[k]){
```

To be:

```
if(list.get(i) == list.get(k)){
```

Second, you should add a condition to make sure `i != k` (or in other words - you're not comparing an element to itself.

And third, you can't access a list like you do: `list[i]` you should use `list.get(i)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
public void compareElementToList() {

    List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(1.0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Double itemI = list.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
            Double itemJ = list.get(j);
            if (i != j) {
                if (itemI.compareTo(itemJ) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Element " + i + " and " + j + " are pairs.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("There are no even elements.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Element omited.");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A list is basically just a variable length array. You can access data from it with the get(int) method which gets the n-th value from the list and set(int, Object) to set the n-th value to the given object.

The javadocs are your friends. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html