# how to compare items in the list in java?

Tags: java

I am writing a to-do list and I am trying to sort my array with the input of the user that is a string but it is a date.

I wrote this code but it did not work

```
public static void kir() {
    ArrayList <String> x = new ArrayList <>() {
        {
            add("dsadsadasd 2020-09-09");
            add("dadsaasdas 2019-10-10");
            add("dadadada 2021-10-09");
        }
    };
    ArrayList <String> y = new ArrayList <>();
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (x.size() - 1); i++) {
        String m;
        String t;
        m = x.get(i).substring(x.get(i).length() - 10, x.get(i).length() - 7);
        t = x.get(i + 1).substring(x.get(i + 1).length() - 10, x.get(i + 1).length() - 7);
        while (i < (x.size() - 1)) {
            if (m.compareTo(t) >= 0) {
                y.add(x.get(i + 1));
            } 
            else {
                y.add(x.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println(y);
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps getting me the only smallest one. and not giving me the others

Comment: First of, you some proper variable names. What are `x`, `y`, `m`, `t` in your question? Second, don't use double braces array initialisation (https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/08/dont-be-clever-the-double-curly-braces-anti-pattern/)

Comment: alright, but any solutions?

Comment: Does your program crash or does it end properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing elements in the same List Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535346/comparing-elements-in-the-same-list-java)

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? Sorry, but guessing what `x.get(i).substring(x.get(i).length()-10,x.get(i).length()-7)` was meant to mean is impossible for me with those variable names and magic numbers.

Comment: so, basically, it means the last 10 characters in the string till the 7th last character should be compared since I add the dates at the end so it is always the same.

Comment: _"I add the dates at the end"_, maybe you would be better of with a simple POJO class that holds the string and the date as tow separate variables.

Answer (score 2):

It is a huge leap to deeper levels of java, but the elegant way would be:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(list,
    "dsadsadasd 2020-09-09", "dadsaasdas 2019-10-10", "dadadada 2021-10-09");
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.substring(s.length()-10))
                    .thenComparing(s -> s.substring(0, s.length()-10)));
```

- List has a `sort` method, also with a Comparator for *how* to compare two items (Strings here). [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) has methods to build a -1/0/+1 comparator from a lambda
  (function) to generate a key. Above the two lambdas specify there own local parameter variable `s`, a String, for which coincidentally also a String key is generated, to be used in comparing two list elements.
- In java one often declares a variable with the most general assumption (`List<String> list`) and selects an implementation (`new ArrayList<>()`). The implementation may change - `new LinkedList()` - yet still the rest of the code will remain compilable.

Answer (score 0):

Create a POJO class to hold your ToDo items and let the class implement the `Comparable` interface for sorting

```
public class ToDoItem implements Comparable<ToDoItem> {
    String item;
    LocalDate date;

    //getters and setters...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ToDoItem item) {
        return this.date.compareTo(item.getDate());
    } 
}
```